# setInterval for the random function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I need to set the time interval of about 1sec for this function:

```
  function random_imglink(){
    var myimages=new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/standalone.swf"
    myimages[2]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/mobil.swf"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)

    if (ry==0)
    ry=1
    document.write('<embed wmode="transparent" src="'+myimages[ry]+'" height="253" width="440"></embed>')
  } 
    random_imglink()
```

Please smb help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the function once then use "setTimeout". If you want to call the function continuously then use "setInterval"

e.g

```
var intervalID = setInterval( "random_imglink()", 1000 );
```

Note: You can then stop the function being called by using:

```
clearInterval( intervalID );
```

Answer (score 1):

easy:

```
setTimeout("javascript statement",milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval(random_imglink, 1000);`

See also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

```
var random_imglink = function(){
    // [...]
} 
setTimeout( random_imglink, 1000  )
```